# Need some help proving that if a|b and |b| < a then b = 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I just want to ask for a bit of help.

I have to prove the next:

If $a|b$ and $|b| \lt a$ then $b=0$

I know basics like:

If $a|b \Rightarrow$ $\exists k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $b = ak$

$\Rightarrow |b| = |ak| \Rightarrow |b|= |a||k|$

But I'm not sure how to proceed, or if the above it's right for this proof

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there: if $b\ne0$, then $k\ne0$, and therefore (since $k\in\Bbb Z$) $|k|\geqslant1$. So,$$|b|=|a||k|\geqslant|a|\geqslant a.$$

Comment: Ehm I kind of understand, but could you ( or anyone) give me more feedback about why |b|=|a||k|⩾|a|⩾a proof that b=0

Comment: I *assumed* that $b\ne0$, and I *deduced* from that that $|b|\geqslant a$. But you know that, in fact, $|b|<a$. So, the assumption that $b\ne0$ is wrong, and therefore $b=0$.

Comment: Oh now I fully understand, ty